# Python Extract Multiple Strings Many Times Between Asterisks

Tags: python, string

I looked around, but couldn't find what I was looking for....

Basically I have a string with lots of asterisks scattered around:

Example: `red blue green * hello* pink orange 4pgp42g4jg42 * world* violet black`

What I am trying to do is split the string up so I can extract "hello" and "world" and eventually print them out as a list using a for statement. The strings I'm working with are longer and do not necessarily have any set number of slices that I would want to take out.

Could anyone assist me with this please?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you ever tried the `re` module? It uses a syntax called regular expression that allows you to do very complicated matches (see the docs [here](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html)). In your case, you could try something like this:

```
import re

# Store your string
my_str = 'red blue green * hello* pink orange 4pgp42g4jg42 * world* violet black'

# Find matches
match = re.findall(r'\*([^\*]*)\*', my_str)

# Print everything
print match

# Iterate
for item in match:
    print item
```

Comment: Happy it helps! Hopefully you'll get some good usage of it in the future. The `split` method mentioned by some the other posters is pretty cool as well. Have fun!

Answer (score 7):

I would expect that:

```
re.findall(r'\*([^*]+)\*',string)
```

would do the trick.  Basically this regex looks for a `'*'` (`\*`) and then matches anything that isn't a `'*'` (`([^*]+)`) and then another `'*'`.

Comment: would this also work if the example started `red blue * green * hello*`...?

Comment: Nope.  To get that, you could probably use: `r'\*([^*]+)'` (I removed the necessity to have an asterisk at the end too).

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to the excellent `re` suggestions:

Use `split` to separate sections of "between asterisks" and "not between asterisks":

```
>>> msg = "red blue green * hello* pink orange 4pgp42g4jg42 * world* violet black"
>>> msg.split()
['red blue green ', ' hello', ' pink orange 4pgp42g4jg42 ', ' world', ' violet black']
```

Then use array slicing to get every other section, starting with the second.

```
>>>msg.split("*")[1::2]
[' hello', ' world']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use .split('*') and then take every other element.

For instance:

```
my_string = 'this is a *test* of my code that *I* have written'
split_string = my_string.split('*')
words_between = [split_string[i] for i in range(1, len(split_string), 2)]
```

Comment: Taking every other element is done easier using a "stride" when slicing (as demonstrated by @Kevin).

Answer (score 1):

Regex seems like overkill here.  I would just use:

```
my_str = 'red blue green * hello* pink orange 4pgp42g4jg42 * world* violet black'
broken_up = my_str.split('*')
```

And if you don't want the ends, just do

```
broken_up[1:-1]
```

EDIT:
I think I just realized what you're really looking for.  Technically 'pink orange 4pgp42g4jg42' is between asterisks too, which poses a problem.  I think that this'll work though.

```
my_str = 'red blue green * hello* pink orange 4pgp42g4jg42 * world* violet black'
broken_up = my_str.split('*')
broken_up = [broken_up[i] for i in range(1, len(broken_up), 2)]
```

If you want to get rid of spaces, just use .strip() like

```
broken_up = [broken_up[i].strip() for i in range(1, len(broken_up), 2)]
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but the OP asked for a list that can be run through with a for loop.

Comment: please read the question first, OP wants to extract the words between `*`s, and this `split('*')` is already been posted by 2 users.

Comment: Yeah, we posted them at the same time so yell at them too.  And this gives the words between the asterisks, and the words on the ends of the list.  It's never clearly stated what the OP wants and I've read the question three times.

Comment: Yeah, I fixed it. I couldn't figure out exactly what he wanted at first. You were right, my bad.  Either way, got it now.  Now that I know exactly what he wants, regex might be a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
from re import findall

sstring = "red blue green * hello* pink orange 4pgp42g4jg42 * world*"

result = findall('\*.*?\*', sstring)
print r
```

This will give you:

```
['* hello*', '* world*']
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this using re.split to split this into a list of strings thusly:

```
import re

my_string = "red blue green * hello* pink orange 4pgp42g4jg42 * world* violet black"

all_split_up = re.split('\*', my_string)
```

When you do this, typing:

```
for item in all_split_up:
    print item
```

will yield:

```
red blue green 
 hello
 pink orange 4pgp42g4jg42 
 world
 violet black
```

By using re.split instead of re.findall, you won't have to worry about specifying non-capturing groups in the regex pattern. I think this is the simplest regex answer though a little late on the 'Answer' button.

Comment: Was surprised that everybody had used re.findall instead of just re.split...didn't even think of just using the built in string split. Nice.